# Mongoose optional minlength validator?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I have an optional `string` field type with a `minlength`.  The docs [(linked here)](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-minlength) do not go into detail on this?  I have been trying:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 255 },
    nickname: { type: String, minlength: 4, maxlength: 255 }
});
```

Every variation I try returns some type of error.

My goal is to evaluate the `minlength` and `maxlength` **only if** the value has been supplied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** write a mongoose plugin.

**Long answer:**

You can add extra attributes to the schema that you desire.  You generally write a Mongoose **Plugin** to actually do something with them.  An example of this would be the [mongoose-hidden](https://github.com/mblarsen/mongoose-hidden) plugin which allows you to define some of your fields as **hidden** during conversion:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  password: { type: String, hide: true }
});
userSchema.plugin(require('mongoose-hidden'));

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users');
var user = new User({ name: 'Val', password: 'pwd' });
// Prints `{ "name": "Val" }`. No password!
console.log(JSON.stringify(user.toObject()));
```

Note the `hide: true` attribute on the `password:` field.  The plugin overrides the `toObject()` function and the custom version removes looks for the attribute and removes the field.

Here's the body of the plugin.  Line #4 looks checks for the existence of the `schemaType.options.hide` attribute:

```
function HidePlugin(schema) {
  var toHide = [];
  schema.eachPath(function(pathname, schemaType) {
    if (schemaType.options && schemaType.options.hide) {
      toHide.push(pathname);
    }    
  });
  schema.options.toObject = schema.options.toObject || {};
  schema.options.toObject.transform = function(doc, ret) {
    // Loop over all fields to hide
    toHide.forEach(function(pathname) {
      // Break the path up by dots to find the actual
      // object to delete
      var sp = pathname.split('.');
      var obj = ret;
      for (var i = 0; i < sp.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (!obj) {
          return;
        }
        obj = obj[sp[i]];
      }
      // Delete the actual field
      delete obj[sp[sp.length - 1]];
    });

    return ret;
  };
}
```

**My point is...**

... if you write a mongoose plugin (for example, maybe the "MinLengthPlugin") you could reuse this on all of your schemas without writing any additional code.  Within the plugin you *could* override the functionality with something like:

```
module.exports = function MinLenghPlugin (schema, options) {

    schema.pre('save', myCustomPreSaveHandler);

    var myCustomPreSaveHandler = function() {
       // your logic here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that you can do it with built-in validators, but you can by using a custom one:

```
var optionalWithLength = function(minLength, maxLength) {
  minLength = minLength || 0;
  maxLength = maxLength || Infinity;
  return {
    validator : function(value) {
      if (value === undefined) return true;
      return value.length >= minLength && value.length <= maxLength;
    },
    message : 'Optional field is shorter than the minimum allowed length (' + minLength + ') or larger than the maximum allowed length (' + maxLength + ')'
  }
}

// Example usage:
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name    : { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 255 },
    nickname: { type: String, validate: optionalWithLength(4, 255) }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do with built-in validators.

> My goal is to evaluate the `minlength` and `maxlength` only if the value has been supplied.

if a value is greater than 12 and value is equal to 0 then no error will generate but if one of the conditions is wrong than it will generate validation error.

```
enrollment_no: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    // minlength: [12, 'Enrollment number must be at least 12 characters long'],
    maxlength: [16, 'Enrollment number is not allowed more than 16'],
    validate: {
        validator: function(val) {
            return val.length >= 12 || val.length === 0
        },
        message: () => `Enrollment number must be at least 12 characters long`
    },
    default: null
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same predicament wanted a String that is optional, unique with minimum length and validation, so I used multiple validators to do the trick also used a '*pre*' save method to delete empty/null values so no duplicates since empty Strings are not unique

```
var validateUserNameLength = function (username) {
    if (username && username.length !== '') {
        return username.length >= 3;
    }
   return true;
};

var validateUserNameFormat = function (username) {
    if (username && username.length) {
        return username !== 'foo;
    }
    return true;
 }


var validateUserName= [
    { validator: validateUserNameLength , msg: 'short UserName' },
    { validator: validateUserNameFormat , msg: 'No Foo name' }
]; 

var UserSchema= mongoose.Schema({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        index: {
            unique: true,
            sparse: true
        },
        validate: validateUserName,
        maxlength: [20, 'long UserName']
    },
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
   if (this.userName === null || this.userName === '') {
       this.userName = undefined;
   }

   next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a custom validator/plugin is not necessary for this task.

If the value is not required (`required: false`), then not providing it (or providing `null`) will not trigger the min/max length validation.
If you want to allow either an empty string or a string constrained by min/max length, simply use a [match](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-match) regex to test for this, e.g. `/^$|^.{4, 255}$/`, or dynamically construct a `new RegExp("^$|^.{" + minLength + "," + maxLength + "}$")`.

Tested on mongoose 4.7.8